# Seeming ambiguity when evaluating a function involving arctan? What am I missing?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

I'm trying to evaluate the following exactly:
$$\cos(\tan^{-1}(2)+\tan^{-1}(3))$$

There's a few ways to get the answer of $-\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$.  I'm interested in this particular path using the $\tan^{-1}(a)+\tan^{-1}(b) $ [addition identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Arctangent_addition_formula).  Here are the first few steps without issue:
$$\cos(\tan^{-1}(2)+\tan^{-1}(3))=\cos(\tan^{-1}(\frac{2+3}{1-2*3}))$$
$$=\cos(\tan^{-1}(-1))$$

At this point it seems straight forward to me to finish the evaluation, $-1$ can be written as $\tan(-\frac{\pi}{4})$ so we continue:
$$\cos(\tan^{-1}(\tan(-\frac{\pi}{4}))=\cos(-\frac{\pi}{4})=+\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$$
Oops...Note that we can force the "right" answer if we shift things around a bit:
$$\cos(\tan^{-1}(-1))=\cos(\tan^{-1}(-\tan(\frac{\pi}{4})))=\cos(\tan^{-1}(\tan(\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}))$$
$$\cos(\pi-\frac{\pi}{4})=-\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$$
Where did I go wrong here?  What needs to be specified at the beginning to avoid the ambiguity or what convention am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: This may be of help: According to wolfram, $\cos(\arctan(2)+\arctan(3))\ne \cos(\arctan(-1))$.

Comment: Thank you, I don't think that helps though. Why wouldn't the $\tan(a+b)$ identity not apply here (replacing $a$ with $\tan^{-1}(a)$ and $b$ with $\tan^{-1}(b)$)?  Or am I really missing something simple.

Comment: It seems you have found that $\tan(\arctan(2)+\arctan(3))=-1$ but it is not necessarily true that $\arctan(2)+\arctan(3)=\arctan(-1)$ (see the definition of arctan). Another simple wolfram query tells us that $\arctan(-1)-\arctan(2)-\arctan(3)=-\pi$.

Comment: The addition formula for arctan you refer to, is mod pi. Did you take that into account in your computation?

Comment: Note that $\frac\pi4\lt\arctan(2),\arctan(3)\lt\frac\pi2$. Thus, $\frac\pi2\lt\arctan(2)+\arctan(3)\lt\pi$. So, indeed $\tan\left(\arctan(2)+\arctan(3)\right)=-1$, but $\arctan(2)+\arctan(3)\ne\arctan(-1)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed a key part of the [addition identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Arctangent_addition_formula):

> $\arctan(u) + \arctan(v) = \arctan(\frac{u + v}{1 - uv})$    **(mod $\pi$)**

[my emphasis added on that **(mod $\pi$)**]

In words, after computing the quantity $\arctan(\frac{u \pm v}{1 \mp uv})$, you must then examine the input values $u$ and $v$ and use them to determine whether to add or subtract $\pi$ to get the correct answer for $\arctan(u) + \arctan(v)$. Determining whether $\pi$ gets added or subtracted can affect the positivity or negativity of the quantity $\cos(\arctan(u) + \arctan(v))$, because of the identity $\cos(\theta \pm \pi) = - \cos(\theta)$.

In your example, one can determine whether $\pi$ must be added or subtracted as follows. First, $\arctan(2)$ is the angle of the line of slope $2$ which lies in the interval $(\pi/4,\pi/2)$. And then, similarly, $\arctan(3)$ lies in that same interval $(\pi/4,\pi/2)$. Their sum $\arctan(2) + \arctan(3)$ is therefore an angle lying in the interval $(\pi/2,\pi)$. But the output of the $\arctan(...)$ on the right side of the addition identity is an angle in the interval $(-\pi/2,+\pi/2)$, so you must add $\pi$ to get a value in the interval $(\pi/2,3\pi/2)$, and when that's done you will have the correct value equal to the left hand side of the addition identity.

To summarize, what matters is not only the *quadrants* of the two angles $\arctan(u)$ and $\arctan(v)$, but their *half-quadrants*: in order to determine whether to add or subtract $\pi$ when using the addition identity, you must determine which of the four intervals the angles $\arctan(u)$ and $\arctan(v)$ lie in, namely:
$$(-\pi/2,-\pi/4], [-\pi/4,0], [0,\pi/4], [\pi/4,\pi/2)
$$
And that depends on which of the four intervals your inputs $u$ and $v$ line in, namely:
$$(\infty,-1], [-1,0], [0,+1], [+1,+\infty)
$$

Comment: The identity $\cos(\theta+\pi)=-\cos\pi$ should be $-\cos\theta$ on the right.

Comment: Oops, thanks for the fix.